# "The response from a findAll must be an Array, not undefined" - potentially incorrect serialisation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js

Just getting started with Ember, and I'm following [this tutorial](http://ember.vicramon.com/).

I've got the Ember app set up, the Route and the Model, except when I hit the Route, I get a large number of warnings printed to the console, followed by the error in the title.

My Model looks like:

```
App = DS.Model.extend
  firstName: DS.attr('string')
  lastName: DS.attr('string')
  email: DS.attr('string')
  phone: DS.attr('string')
  status: DS.attr('string', defaultValue: 'new')
  notes: DS.attr('string')
```

And my Route:

```
App.LeadsRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: -> @store.find 'lead'
```

My Store.js:

```
App.ApplicationStore = DS.Store.extend({

})

# Override the default adapter with the `DS.ActiveModelAdapter` which
# is built to work nicely with the ActiveModel::Serializers gem.
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.ActiveModelAdapter.extend({

})
```

The JSON my Rails app is returning looks [like this](https://gist.github.com/nikz/ca310b8a4d97233df0dd).

The warnings are:

```
WARNING: Encountered "0" in payload, but no model was found for model name "0" (resolved     model name using DS.ActiveModelSerializer.typeForRoot("0"))
```

(I get one warning for each Lead in the Database)

And the error is:

```
Error while processing route: leads Assertion Failed: The response from a findAll must be an Array, not undefined Error: Assertion Failed: The response from a findAll must be an Array, not undefined
```

Which seems to be a pretty common one, if StackOverflow search is anything to go by :)

Help greatly appreciated!

Thanks,

Nik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I figured this one out... for list responses, ember-data/ActiveModelAdapter is expecting responses formatted like this:

```
{ "leads" : [ { id: 123, name: "Test", ... }, { id: 456, name: "Test 2", ... } ] }
```

Whereas I was sending

```
[ { "lead": { id: 123, name: "Test", ... } }, { "lead": { id: 456, name: "Test 2", ... }} ] }
```

Comment: Hello, I am following the same tutorial and although I understand that you sent a response back from Rails in a different format, what did you do to actually change the format?

Comment: Hi, I tweaked the options on active_model_serializers - used embed :ids with the include option. Hope that helps!

Comment: Not a ton of help. : /

Comment: Hi sheriffderek - if you're using the 0.8.x version of AMS, you can specify "embed :ids, include: true" to embed associations by id rather than embedding the full representation of the associated object, which seems to be what Ember expects. Let me know if that helps!